# Add element outside of array to csv output

Tags: json, export-to-csv, jq

I have a JSON structure similar to this one:

```json
{
  "results": [
    {
      "title": "Page 1",
      "content": {
        "id": "11111"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Page 2",
      "content": {
        "id": "22222"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Page 3",
      "content": {
        "id": "33333"
      }
    }
  ],
  "start": 0,
  "limit": 25,
  "size": 3,
  "totalSize": 3,
  "query": "Hello World"
}
```

The output I need is:

```
"Page 1","11111","Hello World"
"Page 2","22222","Hello World"
"Page 3","33333","Hello World"
```

I can get the elements from the array with:
`cat my.json | jq -r '.results[] | [.title, .content.id] | @csv'`
But how do I add the "query" element which is outside of the array to each line in the output?

I tried a bunch of options but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a little placeholder to store the value of `.query` and use it back when putting it in array

```
.query as $q | .results[] | [.title, .content.id, $q] | @csv
```

Or put them in separate arrays. The `(...)` around `.results` path ensures, you don't walk to the path below and still remain at the top level node path.

```
(.results[] | [.title, .content.id]) + [.query] | @csv
```